# How can I use xargs to recursively parse email addresses out of text/html files?

Tags: grep, xargs

I tried recursively parsing email addresses from a directory of text/html files with xargs and grep but this command keep including the path (I just want the email addresses in my resulting emails.csv file).

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" >>  ~/emails.csv
```

Can you explain what's wrong with my grep command? I don't need this to be sorted or unique. I want to match all occurrences of email addresses in files. I need to use xargs cause I'm parsing emails in 20 GB worth of text files.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd probably single-quote the regex, to avoid shell interpolation of the regex.

Comment: Try adding in `-h` as an option to `grep` to suppress filenames - it adds them automatically when you search in more than one file.

Comment: `-h` did the trick! Thank you @MarkSetchell

Comment: I have added it as an answer for all to see easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you tell `grep` to search in more than one file, it prepends the corresponding filename to the search result. Try the following to see the effect...

First, search in a single file:

```
grep local /etc/hosts
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Now search in two files:

```
grep local /etc/hosts /dev/null
/etc/hosts:# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
/etc/hosts:127.0.0.1    localhost
```

To suppress the filename in which the match was found, add the `-h` switch to `grep` like this

```
grep -h <something> <somewhere>
```